# Onclick listener within asynctask onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

I have to call one activity to another. The first activity calls the web service using Asynctask and the response is saved in JSONObject.

The second activity should be called only if there is a click after the webservice has been executed.

Is it possible to have OnCLickListener within onPostExecute of Asynctask? I am new to Android and am thankful for any help!

Comment: Yes, why not?.  mView.setOnClickListener(...);  Why not try it before asking here?

Comment: yes you can create onclicklistener on postexecute() of an asynctask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood, so you can make invisible your button and when the Asynctask finish, make visible it. This is the possible code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_information_places);
   View button = (View)findViewById(R.id.idbutton);
   butoon.setOnClickListener(this);
}
.
.
.
yourAsyncTask{
   @Override
   protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
      yourbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
   .
   .
   .
   @Override
   public void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
      yourbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***According to android design pattern of asynchronous task***

- All the UI thread must be done on either `onPostExecute` ,
  `onPreEsecute` , `onProgressUpdate`
- Since `onPostExecute` runs on UI thread i guess you can perform
  `buttononClick` there

---

***FOR DETAILED INFORMATION CHECK*** -
[**ANDROID DEVELOPER SITE**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)